# Store list of words to sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite database with id, name and reason

I have a text file that contains a list in this format:

```
Name1

Name2
```

How can I store each name in a different row? so name will be filled in and reason will be empty

Comment: Please, provide your code and others can help, otherwise it is a little bit hard to guess where the problem can be :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `INSERT` to add individual records into a table:

```
INSERT INTO table ( id, name ) VALUES ( <id>, <name> );
```

where I use `<id>`, `<name>` as placeholders for actual values ( `<name>` is the data from the file, `<id>` you have to supply unless `id` is an autoincrement column ). You need 1 statement for each line in the file.

How you create these statements is up to you:

1. By hand
2. In your favorite text editor that has a column mode
3. Write code and use a library that can interface with a text file as a database.
4. Use sepcialized tools

In the case of 3.) you would rewrite your insert statement along

```
INSERT INTO table ( id, name ) SELECT ... FROM <pseudo-db>
```

Consult the docs of the respective library on how to build the specific statement.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO Students(Id, Name, Reason) VALUES(1, 'Ahmad','');

INSERT INTO Students VALUES(2, 'Aly','');

SELECT * FROM Students;
```

Hence,it will show a list of  name in row with reason column empty.